# How to configure File Based SMS OTP Identity Provider

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I need to configure file based SMS OTP identity provider. I couldn't find relevant xml syntax in the [docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+a+SP+and+IdP+Using+Configuration+Files).

I tried following syntax.

```
<FederatedAuthenticatorConfigs>
        <smsotp>
        <Name>SMSOTPAuthenticator</Name>
        <DisplayName>smsotp</DisplayName>
        <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
         <Properties>
            <property>
                <Name>SMSUrl</Name>
                <Value>url</Value>
            </property>
             <property>
                <Name>HTTPMethod</Name>
                <Value>POST</Value>
            </property>
        </Properties>
    </smsotp>
</FederatedAuthenticatorConfigs>
```

However, it shows following error.

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler} -  SMS URL is null
org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.AuthenticationFailedException: SMS URL is null
```

Comment: What is the version of IS that you use?

Comment: Is 5.2.0 version